# Can a soul in hell be redeemed, going by Mtt 16:18?

Tags: soteriology

We see in Mtt 16:17-18 Jesus calling Apostle Simon the Rock on which the Church would be built and against which the doors of hell would not prevail. Now, when we talk of the strength of a door, we consider whether it can be broken from outside so the enemy can get in. Door of hell is intended to stop those inside from escaping, but at the same time to allow ' easy access' to those wanting to get in. If Peter is strong enough to break the door of hell, he would also be mandated to redeem someone from inside . But the scriptures including the story of The Rich Man and Lazarus  tell us that once a person goes to hell, he cannot go back. That said, Mtt 16:18  calls for interpretation to the extent whether a soul in hell can be redeemed by divine intervention. Inputs from scholars of any denomination are welcome.

Comment: This is actually a more complex topic than one might think. There's a traditional reading of Ezekiel 16:53 that the fortunes of Sodom and Gomorrah will be restored sometime in the far future, because of the intercession of Abraham (after all, He can't *completely* ignore the praying of someone so holy see Jas. 5:16). So the answer is that we'll have to "wait and see".

Comment: @HolyKnowing Are you referring to the book of Jasher?

Comment: I do not think anything can be deduced from Matt 16;18 about souls being redeemed.  Further some stridently dispute that peter was the "rock" on which the church was built because Jesus uses two different words for rock - but that is another question.

Comment: @ארקדיוס I gave the verse I was referring to: "I will restore their fortunes, the fortunes of Sodom and her daughters and the fortunes of Samaria and her daughters, and I will restore your own fortunes along with theirs" (Ezekiel 16:53 NRSVCE) Yes, my friend, a prophecy that the Lord God will restore Sodom and Gomorrah sometime in the far-future is part of the 66-book Protestant Bible, not some Buddhist palimpsest or work of apocrypha.

Comment: The word in Aramaic used by Jesus to re- name Simon was Kepa . It may not have such nuanced meaning like ' pebble'. Kepa had to be big enough to support a   church !

Comment: @HolyKnowing You misunderstood me. I know what Ezekiel 16 says. I was asking about that: "see Jas. 5:16". What is Jas.5:16?

Comment: @ארקדיוס Ah, please excuse my *faux pas*. "Jas" is the conventional English abbreviation for the Book of James. The verse I was referring to was James 5:16 in the New Testament.

Comment: @HolyKnowing Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A key point (pun intended) is that the gates mentioned in Matthew 16:18 turn out to be locked, so that a key is needed to deal with those hellish gates. Interestingly, it is the keys of the Kingdom of Heaven that are mentioned in verse 19, not any keys to do with Hell (or, *Hades,* as in the Greek).

For what the Bible says about keys of Death and Hell, notice these points I have extracted from the series of articles (below). You are entirely right to point out that a door [locked] prevents those behind it from getting out. These particular gates cannot be broken down. They must be unlocked by one with the key. Nobody inside Hell is going to unlock its gates; the prisoners inside it are utterly helpless, but there is One who has the key and he unlocks it from the outside, to release some prisoners into the Kingdom of Heaven. It's not that the prisoners here have physically died and so find themselves in Hell; but they are spiritually dead and Hell is their unavoidable, permanent destination, unless they are delivered from the power of Hell by the only one who can bring them to spiritual life and spiritual freedom, before they die physically. Now see how the hellish gates debarring people entry into the Kingdom of Heaven take various forms, prior to people dying and finding themselves in the reality of Hell. Here is the quote:

> "Are not gates used to keep prisoners imprisoned? Whoever would want
> to break IN to a prison? Only those striving to release the prisoners!
> The Gates of Hades keep mankind imprisoned in slavery to the fear of
> death and to sin. But **Jesus Christ declares, "I have the keys of
> death and Hades!"** (Rev. 1:18)
>
> Ultimately, once the grave has been emptied on the day of the
> resurrection, both death and hell *(Hades)* are thrown into the
> everlasting lake of fire - by Jesus Christ! (Rev. 20:14) Jesus
> releases those who were held in slavery by their fear of death (Heb.
> 2:14-15). He does this by destroying the one who holds the power of
> death, the devil. ***Yet even before the destruction of the devil
> happens, the Church of Christ is triumphing over the various Gates of
> Hades, setting the devil's prisoners free.***
>
> **This world is a prison:** "The whole world lies under the sway of the
> wicked one (1 John 5:19) Jesus came to "preach deliverance to the
> captives" (Luke 4:18) who, like King David, cry out in prayer, "Bring
> my soul out of prison!" (Psalm 142:7) In every generation, the Church
> needs to identify which particular 'gates' are operating on their
> watch.  In the Dark Ages, those were the gates of ignorance and
> chaining of the Bible, so that the masses of professed Christians
> hardly had any knowledge of what the Bible would say to them. There
> were gates of superstition. But in our era we have the gates of
> materialism, and of secularism, and of individualism, and of populism.
> Christians must not spend time shouting to the prisoners beneath the
> gratings when so many Christians are, themselves, imprisoned by such
> things. And ***so much preaching is nothing more than marching the
> prisoners around the exercise yard. They are not set free by
> Christless preaching!*** (2 Tim. 4:1-3)
>
> Only Christ's authority causes those wretched gates to yield to His
> command! Christians use that authority when they unapologetically
> proclaim the gospel of Christ, though it be "to the Jews a stumbling
> block, and to Greeks, foolishness" (1 Cor. 1:23) The gospel is the
> power of God unto salvation! Christ has given His Church weapons which
> are "mighty in God for pulling down strongholds, casting down
> arguments and every high thing that exalts itself against the
> knowledge of God" (2 Cor. 10:4-5).
>
> That's what Christ meant the Church to do, fortified with assurance of
> His power and protection, and Christ will destroy Hades, with all its
> myriad gates, on the Day of Judgement." Source: Rev. Guy R Finnie
> series of articles, The Gates of Hell, in the *Portsmouth Baptist
> Church magazine, 1996* - written by an ordained scholar.

So, **my answer is that various 'Gates of Hell' already prevent millions from entering into the Kingdom of Heaven**, even before they die physically and find themselves (like that rich man) in torments in Hell. That rich man begged for Lazarus to be sent from the Bosom of Abraham to ease his torment, but he was told that an uncrossable chasm between Hell and where Lazarus was, made such a request impossible. When the rich man then asked that Lazarus be sent to warn his brothers still alive on Earth, he was told that they already had God's instructions (in writing) and if they did not pay attention to that, neither would they if someone rose from the dead. His brothers were just as much prisoners behind hellish 'gates' while still alive as was their brother, the rich man, who had died and found himself in actual torments in Hell. The word of God could set those brothers free before they suffered the fate of the rich man. **Jesus is the Word of God. Jesus rose from the dead. Jesus has already set billions of prisoners free from behind the gates of Hell, because HE has the keys of Death and of Hell!** The Church is charged with so preaching Christ that liberation continues in every generation, and ***it is the power of the risen Christ that sets the captives free while bound in spiritual captivity on Earth, chained by the devil behind his many Gates of Hell. Souls can only be redeemed prior to dying physically.***

Comment: Excellently stated. Up-voted +1.

Comment: Thanks, Anne for the well- sourced inputs. But, your averment that some can go to hell even before they physically die, does not appear to be supported by scriptures. Can we say that it is the Final Judgement on Jesus' second coming that ultimately decides as to who should stay put in hell beyond that point of time . To illustrate, Mr X dies unrepentant and is assigned to hell. But his kith and kin and friends pray fervently on the earth for his redemption . Now, will the most gracious Lord not take into account those prayers on the Final Judgement and admit Mr X to heaven ?

Comment: @Kadalikatt Joseph Sibichan   Sorry for being unclear. The torment of hell (as per Mat.16) happens after a person dies physically. But spiritually dead people, even while they live, are the devil's prisoners; they are already heading for hell, captive to him through fear and sin. He uses various 'gates' to shut them in to his system, to try to keep them out of the Kingdom of Heaven. But Jesus has the keys and sets free those who are to be liberated into the Kingdom of Heaven. Then, when they die physically, they have already passed over from death to life eternal. He showed via the rich man

Comment: and Lazarus that once dead physically, that’s it. There’s nothing in scripture that I can see to back up the idea of purgatory and the living praying for the dead to have a shorter time in hell. No, the Day of Resurrection and Judgment still awaits, when those whose names are not in the Lamb’s Book of Life will be cast into the eternally burning lake of sulphuric fire, with the emptied Hell, and Death, cast in last of all. While we live here on Earth, we either respond in faith to Jesus’ finished work on the cross (and so our names will be in that Book) or we don’t (and they won’t.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

When a soul be redeemed, why would it happen in hell and not while he lived? If there was no God intervention, His salvation, every soul will be locked up in hell. God comments on mankind

> 2 God looks down from heaven on all mankind
> to see if there are any who understand, any who seek God.
> 3 Everyone has turned away, all have become corrupt;
> **there is no one who does good, not even one.** (Psalm 53:2-3 NIV)

Paul quoted the above in Romans 3:10, and further said;

> For **God has bound everyone over to disobedience** so that he may have mercy on them all. (Romans 11:32 NIV)

> But **Scripture has locked up everything under the control of sin**, so that what was promised, being given through faith in Jesus Christ, might be given to those who believe. (Galatians 3:22 NIV)

Paul was saying, sinners who have been locked up, will be released as promised through faith in Jesus Christ. This is what Matthew 16:18 actually means: **"the gates of Hades is not capable to lock up the souls who seek God, the souls who belong to His Church.**

> And I tell you that you are Peter, and **on this rock I will build my church, and the gates of Hades will not overcome it.** (Matthew 16:18 NIV)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Peter was not the rock on which the Church was build, but it was Peter's testimony (that was revealed to him by the Father, according to M*att 16:17*).
The testimony is on verse **Matt 16:16**:

> Simon Peter answered, “You are the Messiah, the Son of the living
> God.”

Because of this truth, Jesus being the Son of God, Jesus is able to destroy the gates of Hades, after His death on the cross. And through Him, the realm of Hades does not have any power on His Church.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The question is based on some misunderstandings.

> Trust unto Jehovah with all thy heart, And unto thine own understanding lean not. (Prov. 3:5, YLT)

Since we are not to trust in our own understanding, but to lean wholly upon God, then we need some definitions to keep from drawing false conclusions from our imaginations.

> And I also say to thee, that thou art a rock, and upon this rock I will build my assembly, and gates of Hades shall not prevail against it;  (Matt. 16:18, YLT)

> kago de soil ego hoti sy ei Petros kai epi taute te petra oikodomeso mou ten ekklesian kai pylai hadou ou katischsousin autes  (Matt. 16:18, Interlinear transliterated)

Jesus called Peter “a rock” – Petros – Strong’s Gr. 4074, a detached stone, pebble, a small rock found along a pathway <sup>1</sup>

But, “this rock” is Strong’s Gr. 4073, “petra” which is a large connected mass of rock, a projecting cliff or stony ground <sup>2</sup>

The word “this” is a demonstrative pronoun that points in a direction indicating distance in time or space in relation to the speaker.  One might say “that book on the table across the room”, or “this pen in my hand.”  Jesus was the speaker, not Peter.  The demonstrative pronoun “this” pointed to Jesus, not Peter.  Picture Jesus pointing a finger at Himself and saying “this rock.”  He meant the rock closest to Him, which was Himself.

> and all the same spiritual drink did drink, for they were drinking of a spiritual rock following them, and the rock was the Christ;  (1 Cor. 10:4, YLT)

> He [is] my rock, and my salvation, My tower, I am not much moved.  (Psa. 62:2 YLT)

> Let the sayings of my mouth, And the meditation of my heart, Be for a pleasing thing before Thee, O Jehovah, my rock, and my redeemer!  (Psa. 19:14, YLT)

> And Jehovah is for a high place to me, And my God [is] for a rock -- my refuge, (Psa. 94:22, YLT)

Search the Old Testament, the Hebrew scriptures for the word “rock” when speaking of God, and you will find that God is the rock of our salvation.  The Hebrew word is Strong’s Heb. 6697, which is a rock, or cliff. <sup>3</sup>

So, Jesus’ assembly/church/congregation is not built on Peter, but on Himself.  He is the cornerstone.

Hades,<sup>4</sup> Strong’s Gr. 86, was the unseen realm of the dead, the abode of departed spirits, the grave.  It had gates so that it was shut up and nothing could get out.  And, as Jesus held the keys to those gates (Rev. 1:18), then only Jesus would open those doors, not Peter.

Jesus gave Peter and the other apostles the keys to the kingdom, not to Hades.

> I will give you the keys of the kingdom of heaven,…  (Matt. 16:19, RSV)

Keys open doors, and it was Peter who opened the doors to the kingdom for those of the circumcision (Jews) standing at the temple in Jerusalem on the day of Pentecost who were added to the church (Acts 2), and it was Peter who opened the doors to the kingdom for the gentiles at the house of Cornelius (Acts 10).

The word “prevail” in Matt. 16:18 is Strong’s Gr. 2729, “katischuo” and means to overpower or get the upper hand. <sup>5</sup> That means that Hades, or the grave was not going to always overpower, or continue to hold any of God’s people.  And, that is what Jesus later explained to His disciples in His Olivet discourse about the destruction of the temple.

> <sup>**31**</sup> And whenever the Son of Man may come in his glory, and all the holy messengers with him, then he shall sit upon a throne of his glory; <sup>**32**</sup> and gathered together before him shall be all the nations, and he shall separate them from one another, as the shepherd doth separate the sheep from the goats….. <sup>**46**</sup> And these shall go away to punishment age-during, but the righteous to life age-during.'  (Matt. 25:31, 32, 46, YLT)

Jesus came in His glory, in judgment when that temple in Jerusalem was destroyed in AD 70, and that is when He took all of those who had been held in the prison of Hades out; those righteous to their eternal home in heaven, and the unrighteous thrown out into outer darkness (Matt. 22:13, 25:30).  Then, Jesus threw Hades and the realm of the dead into the lake of fire (Rev. 20:14).

Hades is not there anymore.  Every single person has always been judged at their death (Luke 16:22), and the righteous gathered unto their people (Gen. 25:8, 17; 35:29; 49:33; Num. 20:24, Deu. 32:50; etc.). The place of the dead existed until Jesus destroyed the old Mosaic covenant at the destruction of that temple, and fully established His kingdom.

All those who have died in the Lord (Rev. 14:13) ever since that temple fell in AD 70, have been gathered into heaven as each died to be with all of their people.  They don’t go to Hades anymore.  Hades no longer holds any of God’s people, and no longer prevails.

Neither does it hold any of the unrighteous, rebellious goats, as they are also judged at their death and then are cast out into everlasting punishment in the outer darkness, wherever that is.

> and as it is laid up to men once to die, and after this -- judgment, (Heb., 9:27, YLT)

Our final judgment has always been at our deaths.  Judgment of the soul has never waited for one last day of time.  The last day spoken of in the scriptures was the last day of that animal sacrificial temple in Jerusalem.

So, no one can redeem or pray anyone out of the realm of the dead because no one can undo the everlasting judgment God has pronounced upon the dead, and because the realm of the dead is no more.

You must connect the dots from the Old Testament to the New Testament.  The scriptures work together.  These posts on my blog, [Shredding The Veil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/), show the proofs from the scriptures that Jesus has done everything He told His disciples He would do.  He has not delayed anything, nor left anything undone.

[The Signs of Revelation – Part I: The Time of His Coming](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2017/02/23/the-signs-of-revelation-part-i-the-time-of-his-coming/)

[The Signs of Revelation – Part VI: Judgment Day](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2017/03/23/the-signs-of-revelation-part-vi-the-judgment-day-chapter-20/)

[Coming in the Clouds – Judgment](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2023/02/11/coming-in-the-clouds-judgment/)

[Testing the Spirits – Part II: The End](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2022/01/24/testing-the-spirits-part-ii-the-end/)

[Testing the Spirits – Part III: Daniel’s Lot](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2022/02/12/testing-the-spirits-part-iii-daniels-lot/)

[Hades Is No More](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2022/08/25/hades-is-no-more/)

[The Signs of the Feasts – Part II: Jesus Told His Disciples When He Would Return](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2018/07/21/the-signs-of-the-feasts-part-ii-christ-told-his-disciples-when-he-would-return/)

[It’s Not The End of The World – Part I: What Does the Bible Really Say About These Last Days](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2015/07/18/hello-world/)

Notes:

1. [Biblehub: Petros](https://biblehub.com/greek/4074.htm)
2. [Biblehub: petra](https://biblehub.com/greek/4073.htm)
3. [Biblehub: rock](https://biblehub.com/hebrew/6697.htm)
4. [Biblehub: Hades](https://biblehub.com/greek/86.htm)
5. [Biblehub: prevail](https://biblehub.com/greek/2729.htm)

Answer (score 1):

The OP says "the Door of hell is intended to stop those inside from escaping." I wonder if that is true. According to the NABRE footnote:

> the netherworld (Greek Hadēs, the abode of the dead) is conceived of
> as a walled city whose gates will not close in upon the church of
> Jesus, i.e., it will not be overcome by the power of death.

In other words, the power of death/hades will not prevail against the realm of life represented by God's holy community.

**Can a soul in hell be redeemed?** If we think of hell as a realm with impenetrable gates from which there is no escape, the answer to the OP is clearly *no*. But if we use the Greek concept of *hades*, which is the word used by the Gospel, we may get a different answer.  According the the Apostle Paul, called said to Moses:

> I will show mercy to whom I will, I will take pity on whom I will.
> (Romans 9:15)

And 1 Pt. 3:19 tells us:

> he also went to preach to the spirits in prison, 20 who had once been
> disobedient while God patiently waited in the days of Noah during the
> building of the ark...

**These things considered, the answer must be *yes*. Souls in hades can be redeemed, whenever God wills it. They can also be redeemed if they respond to Christ's preaching. I would go a step further and say that Christ's preaching includes the proclamation of the Gospel by his ministers, such as Peter.**

Answer (score 1):

**Gates of Hell** As a hermeneutical principle, "Context" may not be *everything.* But it is certainly the foundation of good exegesis! So here we have a narrative of Jesus recorded in the vicinity of Caesarea Philippi, in northern Israel. This is the situational context.

Now, this village is famous for being the location of shrines and temples dedicated to the many gods of Greece and Rome. A temple was even built there by Herod to honor Caesar, hence the name, Cesarea Philippi. But the main attraction there was a huge, daunting cavern which was considered the "Door to Hell" (the gates of Hades). It was considered the door to the underworld, which engendered a lot of superstitious beliefs.

So drawing from this, Jesus is declaring that none of the superstitious religions, none of the gods of men, none of the idolatrous customs—the gates of hell itself—would **not** "prevail against the Church."

There is not the least hint here that souls in hell would be given another chance at salvation. Rather, Jesus is adamantly declaring that the Church He is founding is a sure deal! A victorious enterprise. Peter got it right: the Founder of this Church was no less than *Christ (Messiah), the Son of the Living God*. And this ensures its ultimate Victory over death, hell, and the grave. (Revelation 1:17-18)